# my getAverageBalance method always returns 0

Tags: java, class, object

So I have an Account class, and a TestAccount class. In the TestAccount class I need to call my getAverageBalance method to find the average balance of all the accounts I have created. Here is the code for my average balance method:

```
public static double getAverageBalance()
{
if (numberOfAccounts > 0)
    return totalValueOfAccounts / numberOfAccounts;
else
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, it is always returning false on the if statement and I don't know why. Here is the rest of my account class code

```
public class Account
{
  private int id;
  private double balance;
  private static double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;
  private static int numberOfAccounts;
  private static double totalValueOfAccounts;

  public Account() 
  {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }
  public Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) 
  {
    this.id = newId;
    this.balance = newBalance;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    this.annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
  }
  public int getId() 
  {
  return this.id;
  }
  public double getBalance() 
  {
   return balance;
  }
  public double getAnnualInterestRate() 
  {
    return annualInterestRate;
  }
  public static double getNumberOfAccounts()
  {
    return numberOfAccounts;
  }
  public static double getTotalValueOfAccounts()
  {
    return totalValueOfAccounts;
  }
  public void setId(int newId) 
  {
    this.id = newId;
  }
  public void setAnnualInterestRate(int newAnnualInterestRate) 
  {
    this.annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
  }
  public void setBalance(double newBalance) 
  {
    this.balance = newBalance;
  }
  public static void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) 
  {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
  }
  public double getMonthlyInterest() 
  {
    return this.balance * (annualInterestRate / 1200);
  }
  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() 
  {
   return this.dateCreated;
  }
  public void withdraw(double amount)
  {
    this.balance -= amount;
  }
  public void deposit(double amount) 
  {
    this.balance += amount;
  }
  public void awardMonthlyInterestRate()
  {
    this.balance += getMonthlyInterest();
  }
  public void closeAccount()
  {
    System.out.println("Closing account " + id);
    this.numberOfAccounts -= 1;
    this.totalValueOfAccounts -= balance;
  }
```

Here is the testaccount code:

```
public class TestAccount
{
public static void printAccount(Account acct)
{
System.out.printf("%5d $%9.2f %5.2f%% %29s\n\n", acct.getId(), acct.getBalance(), acct.getAnnualInterestRate(), acct.getDateCreated());
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("The average account balance is: " + Account.getAverageBalance());
    System.out.println();
    Account a = new Account();
    System.out.println("Default account: ");
    printAccount(a);
    a.setId(1122);
    a.setBalance(20000);
    a.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
    System.out.println("Modified account: ");
    printAccount(a);
    a.withdraw(2500);
    a.deposit(3000);
    System.out.println("After withdraw and deposit: ");
    printAccount(a);
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    a.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
    System.out.println("After 6 months of interest: ");
    printAccount(a);
    System.out.println("The average account balance is: " + Account.getAverageBalance());
    a.closeAccount();
    System.out.println();
    Account[] accts = new Account[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < accts.length; i++)
    {
        accts[i] = new Account(i+1, (double) Math.floor(Math.random()*100000), 3.0 );
    }
    System.out.println("Array of five accounts with random balances:");
    for (int i = 0; i < accts.length; i++)
    {
        printAccount(accts[i]); 
    }
    System.out.println("The average account balance is: " + Account.getAverageBalance());
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Array after awarding 6 months of interest: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < accts.length; i++)
    {
        Account b = accts[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            b.awardMonthlyInterestRate();
        }
        printAccount(accts[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("The average account balance is: " + Account.getAverageBalance());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you are missing a line inside your constructor:

```
public Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    numberOfAccounts++;
}
```

If you never increment `numberOfAccounts`, I am not sure how you expect to ever get a value above `0`. This is particularly unfortunate because that variable is private, so only a method of `Account` even has a chance of setting it.

You need to add the same line to your second constructor, but you can simplify by calling the first constructor. You also need to add to your `totalValueOfAccounts`.

```
public Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate) 
{
    this(); // call the first constructor
    this.id = newId;
    this.balance = newBalance;
    this.annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
    totalValueOfAccounts += newBalance;
}
```

You also need to update the variable `totalValueOfAccounts` inside every method that modifies an individual balance, such as the following:

```
public void setBalance(double newBalance) 
  {
     totalValueOfAccounts -= this.balance;
     totalValueOfAccounts += newBalance;
     this.balance = newBalance;

  }
```

Comment: I tried that and it gave me an average balance the 3rd and 4th time I called it, but it was wrong. and still 0.0 the first two times i call it

Comment: Its for a homework assignment and the professor said that the account class file is correct, so I'm really lost.

Comment: @user1054757, Professors do not always write correct code. I'm going to update.